# Ranges TS breaking changes?

Tags: c++, range, std, stl-algorithm, range-v3

It is said that the injection of the Ranges TS into the `std` namespace would cause a number of breaking changes to the standard library (e.g. [this link](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2016/11/25/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-issaquah-november-2016/)). Does anybody know what those changes are?

Comment: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4569.pdf - Annex B, Compatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [N4569 Annex B](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4569.pdf) (as linked by @Holt in the comments above):

- Algorithm Return Types -- modified to include the end iterator
- Stronger Constraints -- algorithms that used to require just `<` now require all comparison operators
- Constrained Functional Objects -- Constraints added to `std::less`'s type and the like.
- Iterators and Default-Constructibility -- Ranges_v3 assumes iterators can be default constructed (in a useful way).  This is not currently required.
- `iterator_traits` cannot be specialized -- in Range_v3, it is an alias template.
- N3351 -- it is also incompatible with the N3351 proposal in a number of ways, which I won't get into here.

This is just a summary.  Follow the link to the paper or find it for more details.

Comment: For posterity: N4569 is ridiculously out of date, although I believe the Compatibility Annex has not changed. [N4620](https://wg21.link/n4620) is the current Ranges TS Working Draft (link broken as of this posting, will start working in a few days when the post-Issaquah WG21 meeting mailing goes out). [P0459R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0459r0.pdf) is a more-current "sort-of-but-not-exactly-working-draft" that includes design changes that were voted into the TS at Issaquah.